# C# check and delete registry key problems

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I'm trying to check (and delete) registry key. Code:

```
 RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
                    ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

                string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;


            if (registryKey != null)           //   <- !!!!!!!!! problem is here, i think
                {
                    registryKey.SetValue("MyApp", codeBase);
                }

                else
                {
                    registryKey.DeleteValue("MyApp");
                }
```

After creating value, application doesnt see new value and doesnt delete it.
What's wrong with this code? Thanks.

Comment: When you are working with registry from code you are moved to virtual registry somewhere to "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node" more detailed read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Check and delete? Then you should move `registryKey.DeleteValue("MyApp")` to the `if` condition. The `else` block will never get executed since opening subkey `SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run` will never be null

Comment: degant, you a right. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your operations for adding and deleting from the registry look good just that there is an issue with your `if`-`else` condition. If you want to check and then delete a registry entry, you should do it like this:

```
string KeyName = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
string valueName = "MyApp";
string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;

if (Registry.GetValue(KeyName, valueName, null) != null)
{
     RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser
         .OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
     registryKey.DeleteValue(valueName);
}
```

`Registry.GetValue(KeyName, valueName, null)` is a better way to do a null check instead of doing `registryKey != null` because registryKey only gets the `..CurrentVersion\\Run` subkey. Instead you should drill down the actual key for your app (eg. MyApp).

Hope this helps!